# Eclipse plugin Javascript editor

Tags: javascript, eclipse, plugins, editor

I want to add hover text in eclipse java script editor. Can anybody give any pointers to some resources?

Comment: What kind of text are you trying to add?  Are you wanting to write a plugin for Eclipse?  The Aptana plugin for Eclipse greatly enhances javascript development if you haven't looked into that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse WDT/JSDT Editor will provide hover text based on JSDoc comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my list

[Eclipse WDT/JSDT](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/)

[VJET JavaScript IDE](http://eclipse.org/vjet/)

You can also go to eclipse Market Place and Search for JavaScript and you will be provided many options.