# any good eclipse plugin for javascript?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I would like to get some intellisense and navigation support under eclipse when editing JavaScript, do you know any good plugin supporting it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse plugin Javascript editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064672/eclipse-plugin-javascript-editor)

Comment: Did you try Aptana? http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download

Comment: @Napolux you should answer the topic, so we can vote it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse JavaScript editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678/eclipse-javascript-editor)

Answer (score 1):

I know a couple of them but I've not *had made any extensive use of any of them to recommend wholeheartedly.*. But you can sure try these ones out:

- [VJET JavaScript Integrated Development Environment](https://www.ebayopensource.org/index.php/VJET/HomePage) from eBay Open Source
- As @Napolux specified in his post: [Aptana Studio](http://update1.aptana.org/studio/3.2/024747/index.html)

Another one that I came across is: [JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly a JavaScript editor but will help while coding:

- http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/
- http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/updates/

You can customize the rules you want to enforce, warnings are shown directly inside the JS editor. It mostly helps me in the form of 'undeclared variable', 'never used' as those hint to broken code.